# Error in publishing jasper Report

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

Can any one tell me the solution of error which is i'm facing about publishing report.

**I'm using ubuntu 14.04 and jasper Studio 5.6**

I'm having main report which contain 10 sub-reports and in that one sub-report contain one more sub-report. while publishing main report the sub-report which is present under sub-report is get exclude by jasper studio. I don't understand why?

I don't understand its an error or i'm missing anything in report.
When i'm publishing my report it says 'Successfully done!' but in jasper server it gives and error ie:

> The server has encountered an error. Please excuse the inconvenience.
>
> Error Message
>
> com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.JSException: Error filling report
>
> Error Trace
>
> com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.JSException: Error filling report at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$FillResultListener.reportFillError(EngineServiceImpl.java:1178) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle.notifyError(BaseFillHandle.java:211) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle$ReportFiller.run(BaseFillHandle.java:135) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$SynchronousExecutor.execute(EngineServiceImpl.java:859) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle.startFill(BaseFillHandle.java:165) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$AsynchronousReportFiller.fillReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:821) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.fillReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:1622) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$ReportFill.runReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:1005) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$ReportRunnable.run(EngineServiceImpl.java:881) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Resource not found at : POS_Billing_DSR_Subreport_Type2.jasper at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getResourceFromLocation(RepositoryUtil.java:255) at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getReport(RepositoryUtil.java:208) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateReport(JRFillSubreport.java:328) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:361) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluate(JRFillSubreport.java:286) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:259) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:459) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2044) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillGroupHeader(JRVerticalFiller.java:639) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillGroupHeaders(JRVerticalFiller.java:561) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:286) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:151) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:909) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle$ReportFiller.run(BaseFillHandle.java:120) ... 9 more
>
> Error Message
>
> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Resource not found at : POS_Billing_DSR_Subreport_Type2.jasper
>
> Error Trace
>
> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Resource not found at : POS_Billing_DSR_Subreport_Type2.jasper at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getResourceFromLocation(RepositoryUtil.java:255) at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getReport(RepositoryUtil.java:208) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateReport(JRFillSubreport.java:328) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:361) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluate(JRFillSubreport.java:286) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:259) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:459) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2044) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillGroupHeader(JRVerticalFiller.java:639) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillGroupHeaders(JRVerticalFiller.java:561) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:286) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:151) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:909) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle$ReportFiller.run(BaseFillHandle.java:120) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$SynchronousExecutor.execute(EngineServiceImpl.java:859) at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle.startFill(BaseFillHandle.java:165) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$AsynchronousReportFiller.fillReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:821) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.fillReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:1622) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$ReportFill.runReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:1005) at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$ReportRunnable.run(EngineServiceImpl.java:881) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

***The Solution for this is:
add the repo and jrxml in the published reports eg: "repo:Sureport_Name.jrxml"***

this happens every time when i publish report and it happens for few reports. every time i cant update repo and jasper to jrxml.

**I tried solution for it is
1. deleted all report from server and myExport folder and re-published again but doesn't work
2. tried to add path in report but that also doesn't work and this ll be not proper soln for me cause i'm going to use that myExport folder in other places 
3. reinstalled s/w but didn't worked**

**EDIT jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version last-->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="POS_Billing_DailySalesReport_Type2" language="groovy" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="0" uuid="ddaeb9ca-aae7-4e61-9615-f25f60294adb">
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.url" value="http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.user" value="jasperadmin"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.detect.cell.type" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.rows" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.remove.empty.space.between.columns" value="true"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.white.page.background" value="false"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.band.2" value="pageFooter"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.1" value="columnHeader"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.band.2" value="pageFooter"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.0101" value="columnHeader"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.exclude.origin.keep.first.report.0101" value="POS_Billing_DSR_Subreport_Type2"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.keep.first.band.0101" value="columnHeader"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.csv.exclude.origin.keep.first.report.0101" value="POS_Billing_DSR_Subreport_Type2"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.report.resource" value="/reports/SMARTORDER_REPORTS/SMARTORDER_BILLING_DSR/POS_Billing_DailySalesReport_Type2_files/main_jrxml"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.reportUnit" value="/reports/SMARTORDER_REPORTS/SMARTORDER_BILLING_DSR/POS_Billing_DailySalesReport_Type2"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="POSConnection"/>
    <parameter name="fromDate" class="java.lang.String">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="toDate" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="hotelName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="foodCategory" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,38,39,40,41"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="wineFoodCategory" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["14"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="coldDrinkFoodCategory" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["17,37"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="liquorFoodCategory" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,16"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="companyId" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="IsExcelExport" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[Select 1 from Dual]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="1" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <group name="DSR_Group">
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="50" splitType="Immediate">
                <subreport>
                    <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="-20" y="0" width="842" height="50" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="1d4602df-49db-47be-84ad-ad22c861f068"/>
                    <subreportParameter name="hotelName">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{hotelName}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="coldDrinkFoodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{coldDrinkFoodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="wineFoodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{wineFoodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="liquorFoodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{liquorFoodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="foodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{foodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="toDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{toDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="fromDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{fromDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="companyId">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{companyId}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="IsExcelExport">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{IsExcelExport}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["POS_Billing_DSR_Subreport_Type2.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <group name="Cancel_Bill">
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="50">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{IsExcelExport}==0]]></printWhenExpression>
                <subreport>
                    <reportElement x="-20" y="0" width="842" height="50" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="718a14a1-286e-4c06-9f2b-9381b0c2a0e7"/>
                    <subreportParameter name="hotelName">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{hotelName}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="coldDrinkFoodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{coldDrinkFoodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="wineFoodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{wineFoodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="liquorFoodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{liquorFoodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="foodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{foodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="toDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{toDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="fromDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{fromDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="companyId">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{companyId}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["POS_Billing_Cancelled_Bill_Subreport_Type2.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <group name="NC_Group">
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="50">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{IsExcelExport}==0]]></printWhenExpression>
                <subreport>
                    <reportElement x="-20" y="0" width="842" height="50" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="498c51ae-a361-4c0f-98e4-e05d973da8ff"/>
                    <subreportParameter name="toDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{toDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="fromDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{fromDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="coldDrinkFoodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{coldDrinkFoodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="wineFoodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{wineFoodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="liquorFoodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{liquorFoodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="foodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{foodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="companyId">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{companyId}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["POS_Billing_DailyNCReport_Subreport_Type2.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <group name="Cancel_KOT_Group">
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="50">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{IsExcelExport}==0]]></printWhenExpression>
                <subreport>
                    <reportElement x="-20" y="0" width="841" height="50" uuid="67c9d02f-cf0e-46f7-a072-31e94e5d0a60"/>
                    <subreportParameter name="companyId">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{companyId}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="fromDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{fromDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="toDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{toDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="foodcategoryId">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{foodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["POS_Billing_Cancelkot_Subreport_Type2.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <group name="Cancel_BOT_Group">
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="50">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{IsExcelExport}==0]]></printWhenExpression>
                <subreport>
                    <reportElement x="-20" y="0" width="841" height="50" uuid="be1c0cf4-a1c7-4cd7-b0cd-cff0b06fa124"/>
                    <subreportParameter name="fromDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{fromDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="toDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{toDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="foodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{foodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="companyId">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{companyId}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["POS_Billing_Cancelbot_Subreport_Type2.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <group name="Reprint_Bills">
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="50">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{IsExcelExport}==0]]></printWhenExpression>
                <subreport>
                    <reportElement x="-20" y="0" width="841" height="50" uuid="556e3c56-0683-41ed-98aa-01a9d888fdb0"/>
                    <subreportParameter name="fromDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{fromDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="toDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{toDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="companyId">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{companyId}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["POS_Billing_reprintbill_Subreport_Type2.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <group name="Summary_Group">
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="50">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{IsExcelExport}==0]]></printWhenExpression>
                <subreport>
                    <reportElement x="-20" y="0" width="841" height="50" uuid="6cd3ce43-0edc-40ee-87e3-e499a178af60"/>
                    <subreportParameter name="coldDrinkFoodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{coldDrinkFoodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="wineFoodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{wineFoodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="liquorFoodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{liquorFoodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="foodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{foodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="toDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{toDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="fromDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{fromDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="companyId">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{companyId}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["POS_Billing_DSR_Summary_Subreport1_Type2.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <group name="summarycancel_Group">
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="57">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{IsExcelExport}==0]]></printWhenExpression>
                <subreport>
                    <reportElement x="-20" y="0" width="842" height="57" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="599a967c-7970-4285-bada-db370e285b5d"/>
                    <subreportParameter name="fromDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{fromDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="coldDrinkFoodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{coldDrinkFoodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="wineFoodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{wineFoodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="liquorFoodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{liquorFoodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="foodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{foodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="toDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{toDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="companyId">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{companyId}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["POS_Billing_DSR_Summary_Subreport3_Type2.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <group name="SummaryNC_group">
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="51">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{IsExcelExport}==0]]></printWhenExpression>
                <subreport>
                    <reportElement x="-20" y="0" width="842" height="51" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="8779a930-536d-4215-a99d-96ed55b9303e"/>
                    <subreportParameter name="fromDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{fromDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="coldDrinkFoodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{coldDrinkFoodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="wineFoodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{wineFoodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="liquorFoodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{liquorFoodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="foodCategory">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{foodCategory}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="toDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{toDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="companyId">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{companyId}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["POS_Billing_DSR_Summary_Subreport2_Type2.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <group name="companyaccount_group">
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="49">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{IsExcelExport}==0]]></printWhenExpression>
                <subreport>
                    <reportElement x="-20" y="0" width="841" height="49" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="8d2cde54-2c95-4912-8498-5edd50111ffd"/>
                    <subreportParameter name="fromDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{fromDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="toDate">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{toDate}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="companyId">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{companyId}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["POS_Billing_CompanyNamewise_Subreport_Type2.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <group name="Group1"/>
    <title>
        <band height="41" splitType="Stretch">
            <line direction="BottomUp">
                <reportElement x="-20" y="40" width="842" height="1" uuid="4338177c-bab1-4305-b8ee-495c03aa9e22">
                    <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
            </line>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="-20" y="0" width="842" height="19" uuid="017a4739-0ade-4f16-9ddd-630f0fb0e075"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="16" isBold="true" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{hotelName}+" "+" Daily Sales Report"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="MMMMM dd, yyyy">
                <reportElement x="-20" y="19" width="842" height="17" uuid="f318ec8d-2fad-40d7-8f79-ee7fd4a1b7f5"/>
                <box rightPadding="5"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["From :"+" "+$P{fromDate}+" "+"To :"+" "+$P{toDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Show the jrxml where you call the subreport

Comment: hi petter, I have pasted the code of main jrxml.

Comment: this"POS_Billing_DSR_Summary_Subreport1_Type2.jasper"  subreport in main report and in this report one more report is "POS_Billing_DSR_DATT_subreport.jasper" is present but while publishing main report it wont be able to find and publish only main subreports

Comment: I see you calling POS_Billing_Cancelkot_Subreport_Type2.jasper why not repo:POS_Billing_Cancelkot_Subreport_Type2.jrxml?

Comment: Hello petter, When i create report in jasper studio workbench and add sub report from main report that "POS_Billing_DSR_DATT_subreport.jasper"  automatically get created by jasper studio. while publishing report from jasper studio workbench it automatically adds repo:___.jrxml. This is only one std way that i know because i'm beginner in this.

Comment: I think my jasper studio having problem with looking for reports as well as in report publish.... I published the same report in 6.4 newer version and it get published without an single error but same thing isn't happening in version 5.6.

Comment: I simply created one simple blank report and called subreport in that and again called one more subreport in subreport, same thing that 3rd subreport is not get published. 5.6 version is stable on Windows but i think not on ubuntu. I can't use 6.4 because it is also having stability problem ie. when i select style/property/... from outline window then he doesn't wish to select other window. Still not getting why he do not add "repo:___.jrxml"